UnsupportedEncodingException for ZHS16GBK encoding
I am encountering a java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException:ZHS16GBK error on my email platform. The reason is that Java cannot recognize the ZHS16GBK encoding. I have encountered a similar issue before with the UTF-7 encoding. At that time, I found a transcoding package for that encoding and resolved the issue by importing it. However, I am unable to find a transcoding package for the ZHS16GBK encoding.
I hope someone can help me solve this encoding issue. If you could provide a transcoding package for this encoding, that would be even better.
